# Spyder won't run Installed Modules - Windows 10

Tags: python, tkinter, module, spyder

I am trying to use tkinter in Spyder and I got the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-2-29b37e014535>", line 1, in <module>
    import tkinter

  File "C:\Program Files\Spyder\pkgs\tkinter\__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I thought that meant that the module was not installed but I decided to look in Spyder/pkgs before going through the hassle of installing it.  tkinter is in that folder, which means it should have been installed with Spyder but I can't get Spyder to recognize the module.  What is going on?

Answer (score 2):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) This is an issue with our Windows installer (unfortunately, we incorrectly packaged Tkinter on it and we didn't notice it).

We plan to fix it in our **4.2.2** version, to be released in mid February.

Answer (score -1):

The error message on the last line says "DLL load failed", which means that the error is more fundamental than a problem with Python scripts. DLLs are dynamically linked libraries used only in Windows, usually created from a compiler language like C or C++.

So, it means that you did install `tkinter` package in Python, but probably didn't install the correct version for your Windows.

> tkinter is in that folder

For modules that contain DLLs or C/C++ code, they cannot be installed by directly copying the source code.

Please delete <del>that folder</del> your own installation. (If you installed that `Spyder/pkgs/tkinter` folder, then delete that folder. If you installed `tkinter` through `pip`, then undo it.) Then, try running the program without installing `tkinter` yourself. Sometimes, the Python installation already includes its own `tkinter`.

Now, regarding how to install `tkinter` properly. It depends on which Python you are using.

- If you installed Python from [python.org](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/), then `tkinter` is included. As long as you didn't override that installation, it should be usable.
- If you installed Python through [Conda](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/download.html), then you should use `conda` command to install tkinter, instead of `pip`.
- If you installed Python through cygwin, MinGW, or similar environments, you'd need to download `tkinter` through their installers.
- If this "Spyder" program comes with its own `Python.exe`, then use that Python instead of your own. It will probably load that `Spyder/pkgs/tkinter` package. And if this fails, then the Spyder program itself is to blame: It didn't ship the correct DLLs. You should try downloading a newer version of Spyder.

Comment: Sorry but I had to downvote your answer because it seems you don't understand the source of the problem. I'll post an answer with an explanation that applies to this particular case.

Comment: No need to say sorry.

Comment: Thanks for understanding.